# JS/JQuery How can I add a class to this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a class to the .question element?

```
$(".question").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

While keeping the current function.

Help is truly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the `addClass` method?

Comment: I'm totally new to coding just learning, and also I need to keep the current function     $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");  Thanks

Comment: You don't have to remove your existing method.  You just have to add the addClass logic to it, like Sanchit's answer has.  Just add that additional line to your click handler.  A function isn't limited to a single operation.

Comment: No problem. That's why the site is here, :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do it by using [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method like this

```js
$(".question").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("q");
});
```

```css
.q{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">Click to add Class</div>
```